# Measure function property

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, definition

I am studying functional analysis and I have stumbled upon the following inequality for $f$ continous and $\mu$ complex measure
$$\lvert\int_{K}f\ d\mu\rvert\leq\int_{K}\lvert f\rvert d\lvert \mu \rvert \leq \| f \| \lvert\mu\rvert(K).$$

My question is, what does $d\lvert\mu\rvert$ denote in this context, there is a note saying that it's variation of measure, is that same as variation of function, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a complex measure on a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{A})$, then, for $E\in\mathscr{A}$, $$\lvert\mu\rvert(E)=\sup_P\sum_{A\in P}\lvert\mu(A)\rvert$$where the supremum is taken over all partitions $P$ of $E$ into countable many disjoint measurable subsets

Comment: This is it, thank you